# Invalid API Key provided error using dotenv env for stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have my env file with the correct test codes. I then added the following to my `stripe.rb`:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
}
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

In my env file:

```
export STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_x
export STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_x
```

I tried with and without `export` and with and without quotations.

Then in the beginning of my stripe.js file

```
var stripe = Stripe("<%= ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY']%>");
```

I believe this is the issue because when I manually enter the stripe key in this stripe.js file, it works.

Is assets/javascript not reached by the env file, or what is happening that made the stripe key not going through?

Using js.erb works locally, but not in production on heroku. I tried:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test, :production]
```

and

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << '*.js.erb'
```

Both do not work in production on heroku. The ENV isn't working and making it through to production.

Comment: you can't use rails code in js file `var stripe = Stripe("<%= ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY']%>");`

Comment: Oh, well what can i use to pass the key through without actually passing it directly?

Comment: You can do one thing, change extension to js.erb instead of js, but tell me why will you do with stripe var ?

Comment: This is a part of the stripe.js file for Stripe Connect.  Just following the docs

Comment: can you share doc url?

Comment: Thanks and adding .erb worked... the docs are here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js and i meant Stripe Elements, not connect but i am using both

Comment: Well, unfortunately, using .erb only works locally not in production

Comment: Its not rocket science. if it is working in local, it should also work in production

Comment: Even tried adding `gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test, :production]` and still not working... Not sure why, any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using dotenv in production, or passing env variables to js/js.erb? and attempt with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55371857/using-dotenv-in-production-or-passing-env-variables-to-js-js-erb-and-attempt-w)

Comment: Have you added your env variables in production?  During assets compilation, you'll need those env variables available in production, in order for it to work.